# Magento - How to manage inventory for two site with same category

Tags: php, magento, csv, categories, inventory

In this article, I use site as physical website, website as the Magento website level. 
Which mean when talk about two sites, that is two totally separate websites, and two websites mean two websites within one Magento.

In my scenario, I have two sites/websites.

The first one is the products we CAN produce. The customers check the website and place order, then we produce them. So it's not necessary for us to manage inventory on this site/website.

The second one is the products we have live stock, we will send them out as soon as when the customers place order. So we need to control inventory on this site/website.

We can regard the products on the second site are some leftover of the first site. So the two sites/website share same category/catalog structure. same customer data, same checkout process and maybe same or different transportation methods. But they do have different prices, special price and tier prices.

Since some products may be obsolete(which will only be shown on the second site), and some may be new launch(which will only be shown on the first site), there might be light different between the category structure.

My questions are:

1. I want the two sites have exactly the same category structure, but when there are no any products within certain category, the category will not be shown on the front-end. Is this possible? If so, how?
2. I checked many articles. Magento only control inventory either on global level or on product level. I do find some extensions can manage inventory on website level, but these extensions are used based on the scenario that the manufactory have different warehouses on various locations. This is not my case, things are simpler in my scenario, I will control inventory in the second site/website and do not manage inventory on the first one at all. Is there any solution for this? Do I have to create two physical separate sites?
3. If we only have few products, this question will not bother me. I will create two separate sites and input these products separately. Since we have over tens of thousands products, I have to import those products by CSV file. I would like the two sites/websites share the same import process, which mean when importing, the first site/website will ignore the `is_in_stock` and `qty` fields and import other informations like description and specifications, but the second site/website will import all necessary fields include `is_in_stock` and `qty` and manage inventory accordingly.

BTW: Of course I should add different price fields for this two sites/websites in this CSV file, and when importing, they will read different fields accordingly. I do know there will be some customization for this, but this is beyond the topic of this article.

My question is do I have to create separate SITES for this scenario? If I have to create to separate SITES, how can I share same category between them? How can I realize the one CSV import will effect both sites/websites, is there any extension I can use for this?
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You would do a little better if you formatted your question so that it wasn't a wall of text.